# Matching literal special characters in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

For some reason this:

```
RegExp('\*').test($var)
```

gives the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*/: Nothing to repeat
```

It looks like the engine doesn't like how I escaped the special character. Is this not the correct way of escaping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to match a literal asterisk, but in fact you are applying a `*` quantifier on the start of string since there is only 1 slash in your regex that is not enough to escape the asterisk for the regex engine.

Use

```
/\*/.test($var);
```

Or

```
RegExp('\\*').test($var)
```

However, the literal notation is preferred since you are not building the regexp pattern dynamically (i.e. the pattern is known at design-time).